# Data input from template file is not storing in .txt file in Django Python ( Get method)?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to store some data from a html form in a .txt file. But when I store data from my variable used to recieve data it give "None". But when I pass string directly it successfully store.

```
def write(request):
p_no = request.GET.get('p_no')
# temp = "% s" % p_no
# Str_value = '{}'.format(p_no)
temp = p_no.__str__()
with open('C:\\Users\\The Goat\\Desktop\\testp\\Files\\sample.txt', 'w+') as f:
    testfile = File(f)
    testfile.write(temp)+
    testfile.close
    f.close

return render(request,'index.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps in the form you use form method="post", and in the view you request request.GET.get.

The following code works for me(**bboard replace with the name of your folder where the templates are located**):

views.py

```
def form(request):
    return render(request, 'bboard/index3.html')

def write(request):
    p_no = request.GET.get('p_no')
    temp = p_no.__str__()
    with open('test12345.txt', 'w+') as f:
        f.write(temp)
        f.close

    return HttpResponse(f"<h2>Name: {temp}")
```

index3.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>User form</h2>
    <form method="get" action="{% url 'write'%}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>Name:<br> <input name="p_no" /></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("form/", form),
    path("write/", write, name="write"),
]
```